# How to access ArgoCD server pod running on EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, argocd

I am creating an EKS cluster using terraform and then I am deploying ArgoCD pods on it via helm charts. Now, I want to access my ArgoCD server UI in my browser but am unable to access it. My EKS is in a private subnet and I am accessing it using VPN.

If anyone knows the process to access my ArgoCD in my browser then please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ingress resource object with backend of it being your srgocd-server service, it would create a load balancer and you can access your UI using hostname. You need to have a alb-ingress-controller to create this Ingress resource and to provision a alb. check these out:-

[aws-alb-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller)

[argocd-k8s-ingress](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/#kubernetesingress-nginx)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <certificate arn>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  generation: 1
  name: ingress-name
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: argocd-server
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: hostname
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: argocd-server
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but can you explain to me a little bit more that first which step I have to take and then which step.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @PiyushMittal first you gotta install aws lb controller on your k8s cluster, you can see [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v1.1/guide/controller/setup/). Now you can create a ingress resource with the above manifest, pls check metadata and choose according to your needs, like internal or external alb, certificate for SSL etc.